# Regex para obter resultado da linha acima

Tags: regex

Tenho o OCR abaixo e gostaria de obter o resultado em expressão regular.

De: `1505 - ADMINISTRACAO DOS PENSIONISTAS DO IPREV`, que consta acima da palavra CPF.

Pensei em utilizar o CPF como parâmetro, pois sempre esse resultado é acima do CPF.

```
ESTADO DE SANTA CATARINA
Contra-cheque individual
Administracao dos Pensionistas do IPREV
1505 - ADMINISTRACAO DOS PENSIONISTAS DO IPREV
CPF: 000.000.000-00
Matrícula: 0000000000
Inscrição: 00000000
```

Fiz o regex:

```
\r*?([A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}\s)CPF
```

Mas está pegando somente o nome, não pegou o `-1505`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema com a sua expressão regular é que o *set de caracteres* `[A-Za-z0-9\s]` não contém o caractere `-`. Aí a expressão regular vai parar no hífen que segue `1505` .

O problema é que, ao adicionar o hífen nesse *set*, a expressão regular vai dando *match* em tudo, até o início da string.

Uma solução um pouco mais simples é dar *match* em tudo que [não](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) seja um caractere de quebra de linha, assim:

```
([^\n]+)\nCPF
```

Assim, dá-se *match* na linha inteira que está acima da linha que começar com CPF. Por exemplo:

```
ESTADO DE SANTA CATARINA
Contra-cheque individual
Administracao dos Pensionistas do IPREV
1505 - ADMINISTRACAO DOS PENSIONISTAS DO IPREV
CPF: 000.000.000-00
Matrícula: 0000000000
Inscrição: 00000000
```

[Veja funcionando aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/q2081K/1)